# Text labels for the identified Clusters using scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I am using Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering in scikit-learn, to cluster texts. How can i get text labels for each clusters.

```
 clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage, n_clusters=10)
```

is there any parameter to get it, or we have to write our own logic for that.

Comment: Is `clustering.labels_` what you want?

Comment: @yangjie  Its numeric 0,1,2,3...n. I need text labels or phrase